# color blending of backgrounds

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made the following figure

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,petri,backgrounds}
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.style={->}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,auto,node distance=58pt]
    \tikzstyle{n}=[circle,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{pil}=[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]

    \node [n] (css) [label=above:$c$] {};
    \node [n] (ss) [label=left:$\text{SelectedStudy}(\texttt{s}_i)$, below of=css,
    yshift=20pt,tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and1) [label=above left:$\texttt{AND}$, below left of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and2) [label=above right:$\texttt{AND}$, below right of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (tis) [label=below:{$\text{TermInStudy}(\texttt{t}_j, \texttt{s}_i)$}, left of=and1, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (vr) [label=below:{$\text{VoxelReported}(\texttt{v}_k, \texttt{s}_i)$}, right of=and2, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (ctis) [label=above:$c_{ji}$, left of=tis] {};
    \node [n] (cvr) [label=above:$c_{ki}$, right of=vr] {};
    \node [n] (ta) [label=left:$\text{TermAssociation}(\texttt{t}_j)$, below of=and1] {};
    \node [n] (a) [label=right:$\text{Activation}(\texttt{v}_k)$, below of=and2] {};

    \node (whatever1) [below of=cvr,yshift=30pt] {};
    \node (whatever2) [above of=cvr,yshift=-13pt,xshift=-5pt] {$i \in N$};
    \node (whatever3) [above of=ctis,yshift=-45pt] {};
    \node (whatever4) [above of=cvr,yshift=-45pt] {};

    \node (whatever5) [right of=a,xshift=50pt] {$k \in K$};
    \node (whatever6) [left of=ta,xshift=-50pt] {$j \in M$};

    \node [n] (whatever7) [opacity=0.6, left of=css,xshift=-80pt,tokens=1,label=right:{\scriptsize%
        deterministic CPD}] {};


    \path[pil] (css) edge (ss);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (ctis) edge (tis);
    \path[pil] (tis) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (cvr) edge (vr);
    \path[pil] (vr) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (and1) edge (ta);
    \path[pil] (and2) edge (a);

    \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \filldraw [line width=20pt,join=round,yellow!20!white]
            (ss.north  -| ctis.west)  rectangle (whatever1.south  -| cvr.east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \filldraw [line width=10pt,join=round,green!20!white]
            (whatever3.north  -| ctis.west)  rectangle (ta.south  -| ta.east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \filldraw [line width=10pt,join=round,red!15!white]
            (whatever4.north  -| and2.west)  rectangle (a.south  -| cvr.east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like the colors to blend the way they do in the following image taken from the tikz examples (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn/)

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know what exact effect you are after and to be honest I find blend modes a black art… But here's an idea.

There are a couple of things you need to fix.

First, it doesn't work putting the background layer inside the blend transparency scope. So move that to outside, so just the three rectangles are inside the transparency scope.

Secondly, using the thick lines, although, a neat way to get a bigger border stuffs up the blend because you get lines drawn on top of fill.

Thirdly, the blend mode chosen in your example Venn diagram works well for those colours, painted in that order. But not so much for the colours you have chosen. It looks OK if you draw the yellow rectangle last. Or alternatively you may find the `multiply` blend mode also suitable for what you are after.

Here's my suggestion for the blend:

```
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \begin{scope}[
        blend group = soft light,
        rounded corners=10pt,
        nw/.style={xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt},
        se/.style={xshift=10pt, yshift=-10pt},
        snw/.style={xshift=-5pt,yshift=5pt},
        sse/.style={xshift=5pt, yshift=-5pt}]
      \fill [green!20!white]
        ([snw]{whatever3.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([sse]{ta.south -| ta.east});
      \fill [red!15!white]
        ([snw]{whatever4.north -| and2.west)} rectangle
        ([sse]{a.south -| cvr.east});
      \fill [yellow!20!white]
        ([nw]{ss.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([se]{whatever1.south -| cvr.east});
    \end{scope}
  \end{pgfonlayer}
```

This gives:

[image: soft light output]

An alternative is to use the `multiply` blend mode, which gives:

[image: multiply output]

Or maybe just use ordinary transparency, which I find more intuitive for this kind of thing than blends:

```
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \begin{scope}[
        rounded corners=10pt,
        nw/.style={xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt},
        se/.style={xshift=10pt, yshift=-10pt},
        snw/.style={xshift=-5pt,yshift=5pt},
        sse/.style={xshift=5pt, yshift=-5pt}]
      \fill [yellow!20!white]
        ([nw]{ss.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([se]{whatever1.south -| cvr.east});
      \fill [green, opacity=0.2]
        ([snw]{whatever3.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([sse]{ta.south -| ta.east});
      \fill [red, opacity=0.15]
        ([snw]{whatever4.north -| and2.west)} rectangle
        ([sse]{a.south -| cvr.east});
    \end{scope}
  \end{pgfonlayer}
```

[image: transparency output]

Here's the full MWE of the first option:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,petri,backgrounds}
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.style={->}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,auto,node distance=58pt]
  \tikzstyle{n}=[circle,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10pt,
    inner sep=0pt]
  \tikzstyle{pil}=[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \node [n] (css) [label=above:$c$] {};
  \node [n] (ss) [label=left:$\text{SelectedStudy}(\texttt{s}_i)$,
    below of=css, yshift=20pt,tokens=1] {};
  \node [n] (and1) [label=above left:$\texttt{AND}$,
    below left of=ss, tokens=1] {};
  \node [n] (and2) [label=above right:$\texttt{AND}$, below right of=ss, tokens=1] {};
  \node [n] (tis) [label=below:{$\text{TermInStudy}(\texttt{t}_j, \texttt{s}_i)$}, left of=and1, tokens=1] {};
  \node [n] (vr) [label=below:{$\text{VoxelReported}(\texttt{v}_k, \texttt{s}_i)$}, right of=and2, tokens=1] {};
  \node [n] (ctis) [label=above:$c_{ji}$, left of=tis] {};
  \node [n] (cvr) [label=above:$c_{ki}$, right of=vr] {};
  \node [n] (ta) [label=left:$\text{TermAssociation}(\texttt{t}_j)$, below of=and1] {};
  \node [n] (a) [label=right:$\text{Activation}(\texttt{v}_k)$, below of=and2] {};

  \node (whatever1) [below of=cvr,yshift=30pt] {};
  \node (whatever2) [above of=cvr,yshift=-13pt,xshift=-5pt] {$i \in N$};
  \node (whatever3) [above of=ctis,yshift=-45pt] {};
  \node (whatever4) [above of=cvr,yshift=-45pt] {};
  \node (whatever5) [right of=a,xshift=50pt] {$k \in K$};
  \node (whatever6) [left of=ta,xshift=-50pt] {$j \in M$};

  \node [n] (whatever7) [opacity=0.6, left of=css,xshift=-80pt, tokens=1,
    label=right:{\scriptsize deterministic CPD}] {};

  \path[pil] (css) edge (ss);
  \path[pil] (ss) edge (and1);
  \path[pil] (ss) edge (and2);
  \path[pil] (ctis) edge (tis);
  \path[pil] (tis) edge (and1);
  \path[pil] (cvr) edge (vr);
  \path[pil] (vr) edge (and2);
  \path[pil] (and1) edge (ta);
  \path[pil] (and2) edge (a);

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \begin{scope}[
        blend group = soft light,
        rounded corners=10pt,
        nw/.style={xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt},
        se/.style={xshift=10pt, yshift=-10pt},
        snw/.style={xshift=-5pt,yshift=5pt},
        sse/.style={xshift=5pt, yshift=-5pt}]
      \fill [green!20!white]
        ([snw]{whatever3.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([sse]{ta.south -| ta.east});
      \fill [red!15!white]
        ([snw]{whatever4.north -| and2.west)} rectangle
        ([sse]{a.south -| cvr.east});
      \fill [yellow!20!white]
        ([nw]{ss.north -| ctis.west}) rectangle
        ([se]{whatever1.south -| cvr.east});
    \end{scope}
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write such an awesome answer. you rock

Answer (score 7):

The blend group needs be inside a single layer, so all the drawing commands should be moved inside a single `pgfonlayer` scope. In addition using `filldraw` will blend the line and the fill, which is undesirable. Here I have fitted nodes around the required nodes to achieve the desired effect.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,petri,backgrounds,fit}
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.style={->}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,auto,node distance=58pt]
    \tikzstyle{n}=[circle,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{pil}=[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]

    \node [n] (css) [label=above:$c$] {};
    \node [n] (ss) [label=left:$\text{SelectedStudy}(\texttt{s}_i)$, below of=css,
    yshift=20pt,tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and1) [label=above left:$\texttt{AND}$, below left of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and2) [label=above right:$\texttt{AND}$, below right of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (tis) [label=below:{$\text{TermInStudy}(\texttt{t}_j, \texttt{s}_i)$}, left of=and1, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (vr) [label=below:{$\text{VoxelReported}(\texttt{v}_k, \texttt{s}_i)$}, right of=and2, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (ctis) [label=above:$c_{ji}$, left of=tis] {};
    \node [n] (cvr) [label=above:$c_{ki}$, right of=vr] {};
    \node [n] (ta) [label=left:$\text{TermAssociation}(\texttt{t}_j)$, below of=and1] {};
    \node [n] (a) [label=right:$\text{Activation}(\texttt{v}_k)$, below of=and2] {};

    \node (whatever1) [below of=cvr,yshift=30pt] {};
    \node (whatever2) [above of=cvr,yshift=-13pt,xshift=-5pt] {$i \in N$};
    \node (whatever3) [above of=ctis,yshift=-45pt] {};
    \node (whatever4) [above of=cvr,yshift=-45pt] {};

    \node (whatever5) [right of=a,xshift=50pt] {$k \in K$};
    \node (whatever6) [left of=ta,xshift=-50pt] {$j \in M$};

    \node [n] (whatever7) [opacity=0.6, left of=css,xshift=-80pt,tokens=1,label=right:{\scriptsize%
        deterministic CPD}] {};

    \path[pil] (css) edge (ss);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (ctis) edge (tis);
    \path[pil] (tis) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (cvr) edge (vr);
    \path[pil] (vr) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (and1) edge (ta);
    \path[pil] (and2) edge (a);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]

        \node [fill=yellow!20!white,
               inner xsep=0.5cm,
               inner ysep=0.25cm,
               rounded corners=0.25cm,
               fit={(ss.north) (ctis.west) (whatever1.south) (cvr.east)}] {};

        \node [fill=green!20!white,
               inner sep=0.25cm,
               rounded corners=0.25cm,
               fit={(whatever3.north) (ctis.west)  (ta.south) (ta.east)}] {};

        \node [fill=red!15!white,
               inner sep=0.25cm,
               rounded corners=0.25cm,
               fit={(whatever4.north) (and2.west) (a.south) (cvr.east)}] {};
    \end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use, e.g.:

```latex
\fill[green!20!white, fill opacity=0.5, rounded corners=5pt]
  (a) rectangle (b);
```

No draw operation, otherwise the border will be darker. Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. You should use the `positioning` library to better position nodes relatively to each other. I modified the `$i \in N$` this way to show you, but your example is *far from being minimal,* so I won't fix how other nodes are placed (this would be too long and wouldn't benefit anyone).

Please provide a *minimal* example next time. Why do you need stuff like `pgfplots` here?! Almost all packages you added are useless here.

You may want to consider using `\operatorname` instead of `\text` for the function names.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, petri, backgrounds, positioning}
\tikzset{
  >=stealth', every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.style={->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, auto, node distance=58pt,
  n/.style={circle, draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20, minimum size=10pt, inner sep=0pt},
  pil/.style={->, thick,shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt}]

    \node [n] (css) [label=above:$c$] {};
    \node [n] (ss) [label=left:$\text{SelectedStudy}(\texttt{s}_i)$, below of=css,
    yshift=20pt,tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and1) [label=above left:$\texttt{AND}$, below left of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (and2) [label=above right:$\texttt{AND}$, below right of=ss, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (tis) [label=below:{$\text{TermInStudy}(\texttt{t}_j, \texttt{s}_i)$}, left of=and1, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (vr) [label=below:{$\text{VoxelReported}(\texttt{v}_k, \texttt{s}_i)$}, right of=and2, tokens=1] {};
    \node [n] (ctis) [label=above:$c_{ji}$, left of=tis, xshift=-10pt] {};
    \node [n] (cvr) [label=above:$c_{ki}$, right of=vr] {};
    \node [n] (ta) [label=left:$\text{TermAssociation}(\texttt{t}_j)$, below of=and1] {};
    \node [n] (a) [label=right:$\text{Activation}(\texttt{v}_k)$, below of=and2] {};

    \node (whatever1) [below of=cvr,yshift=30pt] {};
    \node (whatever2) [above left=25pt and -10pt of cvr] {$i \in N$};
    \node (whatever3) [above of=ctis,yshift=-45pt] {};
    \node (whatever4) [above of=cvr,yshift=-45pt] {};

    \node (whatever5) [right of=a,xshift=50pt] {$k \in K$};
    \node (whatever6) [left of=ta,xshift=-60pt] {$j \in M$};

    \node [n] (whatever7) [opacity=0.6, left of=css, xshift=-80pt, tokens=1,
                           label=right:{\scriptsize deterministic CPD}] {};

    \path[pil] (css) edge (ss);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (ss) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (ctis) edge (tis);
    \path[pil] (tis) edge (and1);
    \path[pil] (cvr) edge (vr);
    \path[pil] (vr) edge (and2);
    \path[pil] (and1) edge (ta);
    \path[pil] (and2) edge (a);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \fill[yellow!20!white, rounded corners=10pt]
        (ss.north  -| ctis.west)  rectangle (whatever1.south  -| cvr.east);

      \begin{scope}[rounded corners=5pt]
        \fill[green!20!white, fill opacity=0.5]
          (whatever3.north -| ctis.west) rectangle (ta.south  -| ta.east);
        \fill[red!15!white, fill opacity=0.5]
          (whatever4.north -| and2.west) rectangle (a.south  -| cvr.east);
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]